# How to know datatype of a cell

Tags: vba, excel, casting, runtime-error

I have been stuck here for a while and getting run time error 13 - Type Mismatch.

```
Dim Qty, ItemCost, Tot
Qty = wi.Range("C" & i).Value2              'Qty
ItemCost = wi.Range("K" & i).Value2         'Item Cost
Tot = CInt(Qty) * CInt(ItemCost)
```

when I tried IsNumeric on C and K column cells they are true but still I am getting that error.

I also tried:

```
Tot = Qty * ItemCost
```

And

```
Tot = CDbl(Qty) * CDbl(ItemCost)
```

And

```
Tot = Qty * CInt(ItemCost)
```

And other different combinations of converting it to integer or double data type.

I also manually formatted the col C and K as Numbers.

Still the error persist. I don't know what to do where I am wrong ?

Comment: how about actually declaring your variables as the type you want. Right now they are set to `Variant` (by default of not declaring a **specific** variable). So `Dim Qty as Double, ItemCost as Double, Tot as Double` (or Integer instead of Double).

Comment: I suggest you convert each value individually to find out which causes the error, then figure out why, if they actually should be numbers.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I declared them as Double specifically. Then I got the error when I assign value to `Qty`. Which means col C has Int datatype values I guess.

Comment: No - it means whatever is in Qty can't be converted to a number.

Comment: None of those CInt conversions is going to throw an error if you have true numbers or text-that-looks-like-a-number (even with a hard-coded currency symbol as a prefix). They will only throw errors if they are text.

Comment: @Jeeped But I manually formatted the whole column as Numbers ...

Comment: @newguy... just curious, what happens when you try `.Value` vs. `Value2`

Comment: Sure. I can type *abc* into a cell and format it as a number. That doesn't mean it is a number. After crashing, hover over the `Qty` and `ItemCost` vars to see what is in them or set a Watch (right-click, Watch) or open the Locals window.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Same error. Jeeped I will do that but I am 100% sure they contain numbers no text. Also I tried isnumeric which returned true

Comment: An empty string isn't a number. `CInt("")` blows up with a type mismatch error. What's the value of `i` when the macro goes boom? Look for the cell that's causing the problem, ***then*** you can say "I'm 100% sure they contain numbers no text". If it contained a number, it wouldn't blow up.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks mate it helped there were certain cells which were empty but they were included in the range when I use End(xlUp) or End(xlDown). Just added a check for empty cell and it worked. You can post your comment as answer so that I can close this :) Thanks Everyone.

Comment: I won't post a band-aid answer; Gary's answer is correct, you **need** *actual* typed variables, and you need a better way to see what's going on. Glad it helped, but then if your code works, I would strongly recommend taking it over to [codereview.se], where reviewers will dissect your code and point everything you can improve to make your code easier to read & maintain, safer / less error-prone, and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need **2** things:

- a better way to make a numeric variable
- a better way to see what is going wrong

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim Qty As Long, Qty_Text As String, wi As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set wi = ActiveSheet
    i = 1

    Qty_Text = Trim(wi.Range("C" & i).Text)
    On Error GoTo wtf
        Qty = CLng(Qty_Text)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
wtf:
    MsgBox wi.Name & vbCrLf & i & vbCrLf & wi.Range("C" & i).Text
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Bonus points for `On Error GoTo wtf` but I've seen the `Sub dural()` too many times. :)

Comment: @Jeeped  I will use more imagination next time ................how about `Sub Jeeped()` ??